# How to match the starting of string & then replace some value using the pattern in bash

Tags: bash, sed, files, pattern-matching

```
vm0 host=10.182.35.1 controller=True
vm1 host=10.182.35.2 controller=False solution=abc
vm2 host=10.182.35.3 controller=True solution=abc
vm3 host=10.182.37.4 controller=False solution=xyz
vm4 host=10.182.37.5 controller=True solution=abc
vm5 host=10.182.35.6 controller=True solution=aaa
vm6 host=10.182.37.7 controller=False solution=bbb
```

I have the above test in a file `file1.txt`.
I want to make the following changes:

- For the 1st 3 VMs, I want it as `controller=True`.
- All subsequent VMs (from 3rd onwards) should be `controller=False`.

I cannot do it using the line number as there is content before and after the above-given snippet.

I need to match the starting of the string & make changes accordingly.

So the output should be

```
vm0 host=10.182.35.1 controller=True
vm1 host=10.182.35.2 controller=True solution=abc
vm2 host=10.182.35.3 controller=True solution=abc
vm3 host=10.182.37.4 controller=False solution=xyz
vm4 host=10.182.37.5 controller=False solution=abc
vm5 host=10.182.35.6 controller=False solution=aaa
vm6 host=10.182.37.7 controller=False solution=bbb
```

How do I make the changes in the file?

Comment: What do the file contents look like before the fragment you are showing?  Does the cut-out content contain strings like `vm3` or other strings that are also part of the data that you show?  How do you want to distinguish the first three VMs; by the 1st column, by the IP numbers, or by some other criteria?  Is this the original data format, or has it been processed (it's sometimes easier to work in JSON, YAML, and XML)?

Comment: [cluster]  
site_ip    
vm0 host=10.182.35.1 controller=True  
vm1 host=10.182.35.2 controller=False solution=abc  
vm2 host=10.182.35.3 controller=True solution=abc  
vm3 host=10.182.37.4 controller=False solution=xyz  
vm4 host=10.182.37.5 controller=True solution=abc  
vm5 host=10.182.35.6 controller=True solution=aaa  
vm6 host=10.182.37.7 controller=False solution=bbb  

[cluster]  
site_ip=a.b.c.d  
Active_host

Comment: File will have some other contents above and below the cut-out. I want to do the changes only for the lines which start with vm$i (i value will be 0...n) So for vm0, vm1 & vm2 the controller=True and for rest vm3 to vm$n the controller=False

Comment: Consider updating your question with that information. It's difficult to read structured data in comments. Is the file in some well-known format?

Answer (score 1):

I'd use `perl`:

```
perl -pe 's/controller=\K\w+/++$n <= 3 ? "True" : "False"/e if /^vm\d+\s/' file
```

Add the `-i` option to edit the file `i`n-place.

Comment: Its working. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

With `awk` you could set a flag once you matched the start of your pattern and keep the starting line in a variable.

Then apply the changes based on occurence of the flag itself and line numbers counting thereof.

```
awk '$1=="vm0" {a=NR}
     a && NR<a+3 {sub(/=.*/,"=True",$3)}
     a && NR>=a+3 {sub(/=.*/,"=False",$3)}
     1' infile
```

You did not define any hint on when to STOP but maybe checking for `vm` as substring in the first field and/or other keywords might be sufficient. The above will only make changes if there is `=` in the third field - which may be happening elsewhere in your file if you do not specify the targets more finely.

Comment: There is no similar sequence in the file so the changes are done correctly using your solution. Its working. Thank you